# UWP app is not found in Store for custom uri

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I implemented activation for UWP app from custom URI. I introduced my schema, handle activation URI in app, added link to my web app page to open it in app.

I released app to the store and everything works as expected if app is already installed. The problem is if app not installed, Windows suggests to "Look for app in the store" and this is where I have problem. My app doesn't show up in search result, nor any app.

My registration looks like this:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
  <uap:Protocol Name="tennis-umpire">
    <uap:Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</uap:Logo>
    <uap:DisplayName>Tennis Umpire</uap:DisplayName>
  </uap:Protocol>
</uap:Extension>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app newly published? Usually it takes some time to get new apps able to be searched in store.
You could wait a little longer and try it again to see if it works then.

If the issue still exists, you might create a [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) to see if they could help.

Comment: The app itself is not new, but the feature of supporting custom uri schema is new. Ok, I will wait few days and update it here.

Comment: Yes, it did appeared after all. Thanks.